# Google Compute Engine PHP API - Virtual Machine Deleted after few seconds

Tags: php, api, google-compute-engine

Following code create the Virtual Machine Instances successfully but after few seconds VM instances deleted automatically.

```
$requestBody = new Google_Service_Compute_Instance();

$requestBody->setZone($zonePath);
$requestBody->setName($instance_name);
$requestBody->setCanIpForward(false);
$requestBody->setDeletionProtection(false);
$requestBody->setMachineType($machineTypePath);
$requestBody->setNetworkInterfaces( array($networkInterface) );
$requestBody->setServiceAccounts($serviceAccount);
$requestBody->setDisks(array($disk));

//Create Instance
$response = $service->instances->insert($project, $zone, $requestBody);

//Get Fingerprint
$instance = $service->instances->get($project, $zone, $instance_name);
$fingerprint = $instance->tags->fingerprint;

$requestBody = new Google_Service_Compute_Tags();
$requestBody->setItems( array( "http-server", "https-server" ) );
$requestBody->setFingerprint( $fingerprint );
$response = $service->instances->setTags($project, $zone, $instance_name, $requestBody);
```

Can anyone help what is wrong with code?

Comment: In order to isolate the issue, do you only have issues when you create a VM using your code? Are you able to create a VM using API, gcloud, GUI without any issue? 

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinginstancewithimage

Comment: I am able to create VM from console.cloud.google 
and using API I can create VM but that VM deleted automatically after few seconds.

Comment: I find the answer: issue was that my quota of creating VMs on google was exceeding. So google delete VM automatically.